# Time Complexity - Inserting an item in the middle of dynamic Array

Tags: data-structures, big-o, time-complexity, dynamic-arrays

I came across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597945/time-complexity-of-dynamic-arrays) regarding time complexity of dynamic arrays which clarified a lot. However I have a case based question. Say I have a dynamic array that has a total of 6 elements and suppose the 4th element is removed. In this case the deletion complexity would be `O(n-index)` which will be `O(6-4) = 2` since the last two elements will only need to move up. Is this correct ? I have articles that give the worst case complexity saying that if the top most element is removed then time complexity would be `O(n)`. I could not find anything that talked about removing/inserting an item from/in the center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your analysis of the number of items that need to be moved is correct. However, in big-O notation, that's still O(n). If you have *n* items in the list and remove something from the middle you'll have to move *0.5 * n* items. But when dealing with big-O we drop any constant multipliers so that's just *O(n)*.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by <blockquote> If you have n items in the list and remove something from the middle you'll have to move *0.5 * n* items </blockquote> How did you get 0.5 * n ?

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. How would you write time complexity for 4 element being removed from a total of 6 elements without neglecting the constant term ? Will it be `O(6 * 4/6)` ? That will give me 4 which is wrong I was expecting 2

Comment: Talking about complexity for a fixed number of items doesn't make sense. Big-O is all about how the computation of time **changes** as a the size of the input **changes**.. For your question (4 being removed from an array of 6) that could mean you're always removing the last 4 items, no matter how big the array is in which case it's *O(1)*, or it could mean you're always removing the last 2/3 of the array in which case it's *O(n)*, or it could mean you're always removing all but the first two items (*O(n)*) again), etc.